# Displaying the Right Icon when Embedding a File via VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to embed a file (of any type) into my word document using VBA.  Below is a excerpt showing how i'm attempting to do this.  I'm able to embed the file successfully, but the icon used for the embedded file is not correct.  My review of the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa211635%28v=office.11%29.aspx) and google searches lead me to believe that omitting IconIndex and IconFileName will prompt VBA to select the default icon...but this doesn't seem to be happening (see picture below).  I assume i must just be missing a step?

```
Option Explicit

Sub test_macro()

' Attach File

    Selection.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject _
        filename:="C:\newfile.docx", _
        LinkToFile:=False, _
        DisplayAsIcon:=True, _
        IconLabel:="This is my file"
End Sub
```

Result:

[image: Embedded File]

Note:  Using Word 2007

Answer (score 1):

You need to add IconFileName and point it to winword.exe and set iconIndex to 0

Comment: Hardcoding IconFileName as winword.exe will always make the icon appear as a Word Document even if the file is a pdf or excel document.  The question asked about any type of file, not just word documents.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32235897/how-to-embed-documents-using-vba for a flexible icon label based on the user's machine and the type of file that is being embedded.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add additional parameter to the `.AddOLEObject method` which is `IconFileName:=`. Based on macro recorder it looks as follows for my computer:

```
' Attach File
    Dim strFilePath As String
        strFilePath = "C:\newfile.docx"

    Selection.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject _
        FileName:=strFilePath, _
        LinkToFile:=False, _
        DisplayAsIcon:=True, IconFileName:= _
        "C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~2\Office12\WINWORD.EXE", _
        IconLabel:="This is my file"
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, however that approach works only *if* you want to embed a word file.  What if you want to embed a PDF or Excel?  It's impractical to build a lookup table for all possible types and it shouldn't be necessary since Windows should already know what icon goes with each file extension.  Moreover, when i perform this operation manually Word picks the right icon! :)  Seems like there's a missing piece of the puzzle here somewhere.

Comment: @Aquadisco,  true and false. There could be possibly a better solution but it's not so complicated. What you just need is to find some `*.ico` files which will represent icons for other type of files. Look, this is my local path to PDF file which I will use as `IconFileName` parameter: `"C:\Windows\Installer\{AC76BA86-7AD7-1033-7B44-AB0000000001}\SC_Reader.ico"`. If I did it quite often I would keep some icons in special folder to used them quickly.

Comment: @Aquadisco, one more thing- in your macro you missed an important part of the code which decides which icon should be attached. Therefore I can't agree that 'there's a missing piece of the puzzle' compared to attaching files manually.